# Fastest way to send data to java socket server from a webpage

Tags: java, javascript, ios, sockets, socket.io

I need to NOT use java for the browser side, because the web interface is intended for mobile.

My goal is to find the fastest way to send a string from an "Onmousedown" / "Onmouseup" or "Onclick" javascript event to a Java socket server, which will then distribute that string to the connected clients and print it to console.

I already have the second part solved, but I am struggling with how to get the first bit.

Socket.io MAY do what I am looking for, but as  far as I can tell, socket.io is it's own server and cannot interface with java programs.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way I suppose is to ditch Node.js entirely and have the page interface directly with your Java socket server via [the native WebSockets API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets).

Instead of having:

```
browser <-> Node.js <-> Java
```

Just have

```
browser <-> Java
```

The nice thing about Socket.io though is that [it has fall-back methods if WebSockets aren't supported](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket.IO). But then again, [if you have a capable browser](http://caniuse.com/websockets), you can just simply use the native WebSocket API, provided they are compatible.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to make a server fast *and* scalable, consider a reverse proxy such as nginx, and forward requests to your Java program on the local host. Then you don't have to worry about threading and non-blocking I/O. Also you can take advantage of protocols such as SPDY to reduce latency.